# Samsung S Health graphs

Tags: android, graph

Does anyone know what is the API used by Samsung S Health to generate bar charts? I have tried AchartEngine and other graph APIs. But none of them have chart animations as far as I know.

Comment: I have no idea and but if you find out comment back.  If I find it I will let you know